# How to bring all dependencies jars with Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, dependencies

I have simple java (Gradle) project wich depends on several JARs, obtained automatically from Maven repositories.

Now I wish to call my jar with external application (Matlab). Unfortunately, application does not see any dependencies after I call `build`, `jar` and similar goals.

Me myself also don't know dependencies, since they are managed automatically with Gradle and may contain nested dependencies, not listed in `build.gradle`.

Is it possible to collect all required JARs in one place to run them freely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom task to collect your runtime dependencies into a jar

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/libs"
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

You could also look into the [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and [distribution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) gradle plugins, that provide similar packaging and distribution functionality